# XBMC on HDMI while Xorg on Official DSI Raspberry display

Tags: hdmi, display, kodi, xorg, dsi

I have an RPi running Xorg Desktop environment on the official DSI display. Is it possible to have XBMC/Kodi or other software working on the HDMI output simultaneously?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in an HDMI display at the same time?